# IntelliJ Error : “Cannot Resolve Symbol” in all Maven and Gradle Dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I creating a new maven project or an android gradle project. After creating; dependencies not loading.(For example Android support libs )

I'm seeing following error in IDEA (Cannot Resolve Symbol)

I can import created project to Eclipse. And i not seeing any error in Eclipse

None of the following worked so far:

- Reinstall IDEA
- Change/Upgrade JDK(jdk1.7.0_51)
- mvn clean install
- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Reimport All Maven Projects

IDEA log : http://pastebin.com/fiiT6RHH

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved ! :)

The problem stems from the fact that the operating system language is Turkish. After Changing to English, problem solved.